# Mozilla thunderbird is not showing my emails correctly

Tags: thunderbird, mail

My email client Thunderbird does not show my emails completely, even the messages that I write down on my composer when trying to send a new mail. What can I do to solve this problem? Attached (hyperlinks) you will find some pics I uploaded, so you can get what I meant. Hope I can get some help from you all. Thanks in advance.

[new mail](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/2643/newmail.png)
[mail composer](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/4397/mailcomposer.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use thunderbird 17 or latest version , some time your sing up is not properly so all the images is not load , so try to proper sign up and completely load your email profile.

for image/pic and attachments, you reset the thunderbird preferences from edit->preferences->set all defaults.

and restart the Thunderbird.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I can not still find that " edit->preferences->set all defaults" option. Just found a "restore default" bottom to set the default thunderbird start page.
Where is exactly that "set all defaults" option?